# Error when executing asynchronous pagination call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-core

I have a ASP .Net Core MVC app where I have a table in a view that is being populated by data from an entity framework query. Following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.0), I've implemented code to paginate the table. For some reason, when the request for the table data is sent from the client side to controller action, there is the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IEntityQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
```

Here is the controller action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetResultList(ResortDataJoinObj resDeals, int page =1)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var resultsObj = (from rd in _db.ResortData
                                  join ra in _db.ResortAvailability on rd.RecNo equals ra.RecNoDate
                                  where ra.TotalPrice < Int32.Parse(resDeals.priceHighEnd) && ra.TotalPrice > Int32.Parse(resDeals.priceLowEnd)

                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Name = rd.Name,
                                      ImageUrl = rd.ImageUrl,
                                      ResortDetails = rd.ResortDetails,
                                      CheckIn = ra.CheckIn,
                                      Address = rd.Address,
                                      TotalPrice = ra.TotalPrice

                                  });

                int i = 0;
                List<ResortDealResultsObject> resultList = new List<ResortDealResultsObject>();
                foreach (var row in resultsObj)
                {
                        var tempVm = new ResortDealResultsObject
                        {
                            Name = row.Name,
                            ImageUrl = row.ImageUrl,
                            ResortDetails = row.ResortDetails,
                            CheckIn = row.CheckIn,
                            Address = row.Address,
                            TotalPrice = row.TotalPrice
                        };
                        resultList.Add(tempVm);
                }
                int pageSize = 3;
                var model = await PaginatedList<ResortDealResultsObject>.CreateAsync(resultList.AsQueryable(), page, pageSize);

                ResortDataJoinObj joinObj = new ResortDataJoinObj();
                joinObj.PageList = model;
                ViewBag.rowsReturned = true;
                return View(joinObj);
            }
            return View(resDeals);
        }
```

It looks like the error is being caused by the line `var model = await PaginatedList<ResortDealResultsObject>.CreateAsync(resultList.AsQueryable(), page, pageSize);`

This line is calling a method within the class `PaginatedList`, which is implemented in its own file (as outlined in the guide):

```
public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var count = await source.CountAsync();
    var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
    return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

There are no pre-compiler or compilation errors so I'm not sure exactly what is wrong here since I'm following the guide pretty closely. **What could be causing the error?**

Comment: Your code isn't paging. It's loading everything from the database in memory, then copies everything in another list. *Don't* use `resultList ` at all. If you want to return `ResortDealResultsObject` from the database modify the first query to return `ResortDealResultsObject` instead of an anonymous type. Pass `resultsObj ` to the PaginatedList constructor, it's already an IQueryable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<ResortDealResultsObject> resultList = new List<ResortDealResultsObject>();
            foreach (var row in resultsObj)
            {
                    var tempVm = new ResortDealResultsObject
                    {
                        Name = row.Name,
                        ImageUrl = row.ImageUrl,
                        ResortDetails = row.ResortDetails,
                        CheckIn = row.CheckIn,
                        Address = row.Address,
                        TotalPrice = row.TotalPrice
                    };
                    resultList.Add(tempVm);
            }
```

This code is not generated by entity framework and does not provide asynchronious calls.
You already have a List when you call the ToListAsync() method so there is no point to cast it to a Queryable and call ToListAsync() on it

The following code should do the work

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetResultList(ResortDataJoinObj resDeals, int page =1)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var resultsObj = from rd in _db.ResortData
                              join ra in _db.ResortAvailability on rd.RecNo equals ra.RecNoDate
                              where ra.TotalPrice < Int32.Parse(resDeals.priceHighEnd) && ra.TotalPrice > Int32.Parse(resDeals.priceLowEnd)

                              select new ResortDealResultsObject
                                 {
                                       Name = rd.Name,
                                       ImageUrl = rd.ImageUrl,
                                       ResortDetails = rd.ResortDetails,
                                       CheckIn = rd.CheckIn,
                                       Address = rd.Address,
                                       TotalPrice = rd.TotalPrice
                                 };

            int pageSize = 3;
            var model = await PaginatedList<ResortDealResultsObject>.CreateAsync(resultsObj, page, pageSize);

            ResortDataJoinObj joinObj = new ResortDataJoinObj();
            joinObj.PageList = model;
            ViewBag.rowsReturned = true;
            return View(joinObj);
        }
        return View(resDeals);
}
```

I didn't test it so there could be some compile time errors but the logic is there :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought I tried specifying the type when creating the objects in the query before without success but maybe I was doing something wrong then.